# Web server to SQL Server integrated authentication

Tags: sql, iis, windows-authentication, integrated-security, sql-authentication

I want to find a solution whereby my user account is passed on via a website to authenticate to a remote SQL server instance.

So if my account name is Domain\Yaqoub, then when I browse my web page which connects to SQL it will pass on Domain\Yaqoub to the SQL Server.

*note - the solution should be able to work even if the SQL instance is on a different domain (which it is :)).

I have read some scenarios where the website and sql server are on the same domain, but this does not really help.

I thought that maybe if you map all the required usernames to the remote sql instance it may work?!

If you could list the steps with a little detail that would be very helpful.

thanks,

KS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for windows authentication to work across domains like you're describing, [**the domains would need to be configured to trust each other**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961481.aspx).

This isn't something that you could implement within the web application or within SQL Server.  Once the domain trust is configured correctly, the standard solutions should work in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your response Michael.

What is the "forest" entity being referred to in the link?

Comment: In Active Directory, a "tree" is a collection of domains, and a "forest" is a collection of "trees"...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory#Forests.2C_trees.2C_and_domains